# cx_freeze: Not a directory

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm trying to create a binary on Linux (Manjaro Linux, x86_64, python 3.4).
My app is a GUI software, written with PyQt.

Here is my setup.py:

```
import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"


my_data_files = ["./images/", "./journals/", "./config/"]


# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"],
                     "excludes": [
                                  "tkinter"
                                 ],
                     'includes': [
                                  'sip',
                                  'PyQt4.QtCore',
                                  'PyQt4.QtGui',
                                  'PyQt4.QtNetwork',
                                  'PyQt4.QtSql',
                                  'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation',
                                  'sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_validation',
                                  'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx'
                                 ],
                     'include_files': my_data_files
                    }


setup(name = "guifoo",
      version = "0.1",
      description = "My GUI application!",
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [Executable("gui.py", base=base)])
```

For now, I'm just starting. The "includes" part in the options is what I used when I compiled my binary with py2exe (it worked, but I want a unique tool to compile for all the platforms).

When I start the compilation with

```
python setup.py build
```

everything seems to work fine, but when I try to start the binary, I have this exception:

```
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/djipey/Desktop/test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.4/library.zip/text_unidecode/data.bin'
```

So I assume I have a problem with the module text_unidecode, but I can't really identify what the problem is.

Could you give me a hand please ?

EDIT:

Ok, sorry for the lack of precision, I didn't copy/paste the whole error message:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/text_unidecode/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open(_data_path, 'rb') as f:
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/djipey/Desktop/test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.4/library.zip/text_unidecode/data.bin'
```

I think the issue can come from text_unidecode, but I don't know why. I installed it without any problem on my computer.

[https://github.com/kmike/text-unidecode/blob/master/src/text_unidecode/**init**.py](https://github.com/kmike/text-unidecode/blob/master/src/text_unidecode/__init__.py)

EDIT 2:
If I integrate the code of text-unidecode (it is basically a single function) in my own code, it works. I think I know why I have this issue. In text-unidecode, there is a file called "data.bin" which contains data used by the function of text-unidecode. It is a part of the library, but it is not added to library.zip when I use cx_freeze. So text-unidecode can't work.

Is there an elegant way to solve this with cx_freeze ? Like an option, to add data files to library.zip ?

Comment: are you sure the problem is not `data.bin`?

Comment: It is "/library.zip/text_unidecode/data.bin", so who is guilty, I don't know precisely. What can I do ? And actually, in "/library.zip/text_unidecode/", there is no data.bin

Comment: Does `/home/djipey/Desktop/test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.4/library.zip/text_unidecode/` exist?

Comment: Yes, but it contains "__init__.pyc" only